# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k {n+k \choose n} p^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations

How can I possibly calculate

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k  {n+k \choose n} p^k$$ ???$$

I tried naming  that as $U_n$ and used the fact that the sum is infinite and that

$$^{n}C_p = ^{n-1}C_p + ^{n-1}C_{p-1}$$

But I arrive at  $$U_n = pU_n + U_{n-1} + T_n$$

Where $$T_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {{n+k-1} \choose n} p^k$$ another sum I can't calculate

So I think my approach is wrong 
Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k {{n+k} \choose n} p^k$?

Comment: Yes that's it thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes our exercise easier if we use Newton's binomial series (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

First, convert the sum as follows:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} k  {n+k \choose k} p^k=p \frac{d}{dp}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n p^k {n+k \choose k} $

Accordance with the alternative expression of Newton's binomial series we know that

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n p^k {n+k \choose k}=\frac{1}{(1-p)^{n+1}} $

After derivation we get the result:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} k  {n+k \choose n} p^k=\frac {p(n+1)}{(1-p)^{(n+2)}}$

Comment: Thanks so much it's clearer now

Comment: You are welcome!